# Area 51 Suspension Queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, account-suspension

With my suspension on Area 51 ending in 21 hrs, I have a feature request for a suspension queue. A suspension queue would permit any suspended users to queue up their contributions to be committed when their suspension is lifted.

I think this would greatly eliminate the need for sock puppeting and other devious tactics people other than myself oftentimes stoop to. Those of us who are suspended but have good ideas could use this new functionality to make sure they get committed once the suspensions end. This feature will also help mitigate the damage that suspensions have on good contributions.

Answer (score 70):

Unfortunately, I believe that this will circumvent the purpose of the ban. That is to say, if a user can simply queue up all of their negative comments then they can just as easily continue their bad behaviour, it is simply delayed.

**IF** it were a malicious user who was banned for ten days, this would give them ten days to queue up hundreds and hundreds of possibly **wildly** inappropriate messages, and have them delivered all at once (automatically) as soon as the suspension ends.

This would end up give *more* opportunity for abuse to the users we are trying to rehabilitate.

Perhaps you could simply take notes and save them locally?

Comment: I've been suspended twice now, they're never for less than 30 days. And, I never got an E-mail telling me why (or what I did wrong).

Comment: @Evan, and I don't necessarily agree with not telling people why they've been suspended. But that is separate from this particular feature request.

Answer (score 47):

I think this is a terrible idea.

Programming a queueing system would cost days or weeks of programming time, and benefit a *microscopically* small number of users.

Any queueing you need to do, you can do on your own machine.

Consider using a text editor like Notepad.

Comment: Is this really a constructive post or a mockery of my feature request? Do you think anyone really doesn't know what Notepad looks like? What value is this screen shot supposed to have?

Comment: I made it smaller.

Comment: @Pekka Risk/Reward and Cost/Benefit would be done by the dev-team. We really have no idea how long it would take to implement. All the moderator only functionality is designed to only benefit a microscopically small number of users.

Comment: @devinb not a fitting comparison IMO. The moderator functionality benefits the whole community, regardless of how many people use it.

Comment: @Pekka, You assume my contributions wouldn't benefit the whole community, and that they're better lost? That's a strong assumption for my contributions -- is it also an assumption you would make for all contributions of people suspended without reason? Or, are you just denigrating me?

Comment: @Evan: The fact of your suspensions suggests that the team thinks the cost of your ongoing behavior are higher than the value of your contributions. Given that your profile on SO looks like a very good users that says something.

Comment: @Evan as far as I'm concerned, you're welcome to prepare as many contributions as you like, e.g. using Notepad, and publish them all when the suspension runs out.

Comment: Indeed the only people who would benefit from such a feature are the suspended users themselves, who I would argue do not deserve such benefits.

Comment: Right clean hands maxim, etc. If they're being punished they must be guilty, and if they're guilty they deserve nothing.

Comment: @Evan: if you think you're not guilty, that's a *totally separate issue*, that should be tackled head-on.

Answer (score 26):

There wouldn't be much of a point in a suspension, would it?

Is that your plan? Preparing the road to `feature-request` they remove suspensions?